# Windows 10 PPP dial-up with u-blox TOBY-L200 stopped working

Tags: windows, modem, ppp, dial-up

I have a TOBY-L200 LTE module connected by USB to a Windows 10 machine. When I try to connect to internet over PPP, I get the message

> Error 734: The PPP link control protocol was terminated.

This was working recently with the same hardware and SIM card. I'd really appreciate any help understanding how it could stop working.

I couldn't find anything that looked helpful in the Windows RAS logs, so the best thing I could think of to provide was the following trace of the serial communication. It indicates that the peer rejected our IPCP Configure-Request twice before asking us to terminate the LCP link. I apologize that the trace is raw and not nicely PPP decoded. Thank you!

```
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    41 54 20 45 30 20 51 30 20 56 31 20 26 43 31 20   AT E0 Q0 V1 &C1   
    26 44 32 20 53 30 3d 30 0d                        &D2 S0=0.         
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    0d 0a 4f 4b 0d 0a                                 ..OK..            
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    41 54 53 37 3d 36 30 0d                           ATS7=60.          
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    0d 0a 4f 4b 0d 0a                                 ..OK..            
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    61 74 2b 63 67 64 63 6f 6e 74 3d 31 2c 22 49 50   at+cgdcont=1,"IP  
    22 2c 22 ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **   ","*************  
    ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 22 0d                     ********".        
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    0d 0a 4f 4b 0d 0a                                 ..OK..            
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    41 54 44 54 2a 39 39 2a 2a 2a 31 23 0d            ATDT*99***1#.     
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    0d 0a 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 0d 0a                  ..CONNECT..       
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] - Open port COM6 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe)    

[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 21 7d 20 7d 20 7d 37 7d 22   ~ÿ}#À!}!} } }7}"  
    7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 25 7d 26 5a c9   }&} } } } }%}&ZÉ  
    63 33 7d 27 7d 22 7d 28 7d 22 7d 2d 7d 23 7d 26   c3}'}"}(}"}-}#}&  
    a0 ce 7e                                           Î~               
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 24 7d 20 7d 20 7d 27 7d 2d   ~ÿ}#À!}$} } }'}-  
    7d 23 7d 26 ad 36 7e                              }#}&­6~           
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 21 7d 21 7d 20 7d 34 7d 22   ~ÿ}#À!}!}!} }4}"  
    7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 25 7d 26 5a c9   }&} } } } }%}&ZÉ  
    63 33 7d 27 7d 22 7d 28 7d 22 86 4b 7e            c3}'}"}(}"†K~     
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 22 7d 21 7d 20 7d 34 7d 22   ~ÿ}#À!}"}!} }4}"  
    7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 25 7d 26 5a c9   }&} } } } }%}&ZÉ  
    63 33 7d 27 7d 22 7d 28 7d 22 6d 22 7e 7e ff 7d   c3}'}"}(}"m"~~ÿ}  
    23 c0 21 7d 21 7d 20 7d 20 7d 36 7d 21 7d 24 7d   #À!}!} } }6}!}$}  
    25 dc 7d 22 7d 26 ff ff ff ff 7d 23 7d 24 c0 23   %Ü}"}&ÿÿÿÿ}#}$À#  
    7d 27 7d 22 7d 28 7d 22 d5 7d 33 7e               }'}"}(}"Õ}3~      
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 22 7d 20 7d 20 7d 36 7d 21   ~ÿ}#À!}"} } }6}!  
    7d 24 7d 25 dc 7d 22 7d 26 ff ff ff ff 7d 23 7d   }$}%Ü}"}&ÿÿÿÿ}#}  
    24 c0 23 7d 27 7d 22 7d 28 7d 22 23 e0 7e 7e c0   $À#}'}"}(}"#à~~À  
    21 7d 2c 7d 22 7d 20 7d 32 5a c9 63 33 4d 53 52   !},}"} }2ZÉc3MSR  
    41 53 56 35 2e 32 30 5a 29 7e 7e c0 21 7d 2c 7d   ASV5.20Z)~~À!},}  
    23 7d 20 7d 39 5a c9 63 33 4d 53 52 41 53 2d 30   #} }9ZÉc3MSRAS-0  
    2d ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 7d 32 c6 7e 7e c0   -*********}2Æ~~À  
    21 7d 2c 7d 24 7d 20 7d 38 5a c9 63 33 d4 77 ba   !},}$} }8ZÉc3Ôwº  
    c6 31 4a 34 45 bf dd a6 aa c0 f6 3d 3e 52 b4 7e   Æ1J4E¿Ý¦ªÀö=>R´~  
    7e c0 23 7d 21 7d 23 7d 20 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 b3   ~À#}!}#} }&} } ³  
    29 7e                                             )~                
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    7e c0 23 7d 22 7d 23 7d 20 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 ce   ~À#}"}#} }&} } Î  
    25 7e                                             %~                
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    7e 80 fd 7d 21 7d 25 7d 20 7d 2a 7d 32 7d 26 7d   ~€ý}!}%} }*}2}&}  
    20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 21 3e 62 7e 7e 80 21 7d 21 7d    } } }!>b~~€!}!}  
    26 7d 20 28 7d 22 7d 26 7d 20 2d 7d 2f 7d 21 7d   &} (}"}&} -}/}!}  
    23 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 81 7d 26 7d 20   #}&} } } } }&}   
    7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 82 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d   } } } ‚}&} } } }  
    20 83 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 84 7d 26 7d    ƒ}&} } } } „}&}  
    20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 2c b0 7e                   } } } },°~       
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Read data (COM6)  
    7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 28 7d 20 7d 20 7d 30 80 fd   ~ÿ}#À!}(} } }0€ý  
    7d 21 7d 25 7d 20 7d 2a 7d 32 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20   }!}%} }*}2}&} }   
    7d 20 7d 21 99 db 7e 7e 80 21 7d 24 7d 26 7d 20   } }!™Û~~€!}$}&}   
    7d 36 7d 22 7d 26 7d 20 2d 7d 2f 7d 21 82 7d 26   }6}"}&} -}/}!‚}&  
    7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 84 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d   } } } } „}&} } }  
    20 7d 20 a8 56 7e                                  } ¨V~            
[16/03/2020 18:33:10] Written data (COM6)   
    7e 80 21 7d 21 7d 27 7d 20 7d 36 7d 23 7d 26 7d   ~€!}!}'} }6}#}&}  
    20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 81 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20    } } } }&} } }   
    7d 20 83 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 66 f8 7e   } ƒ}&} } } } fø~  
[16/03/2020 18:33:11] Read data (COM6)  
    7e 80 21 7d 24 7d 27 7d 20 7d 24 35 21 7e 7e ff   ~€!}$}'} }$5!~~ÿ  
    7d 23 c0 21 7d 25 7d 21 7d 20 7d 24 3d c7 7e      }#À!}%}!} }$=Ç~   
[16/03/2020 18:33:11] Written data (COM6)   
    7e 80 21 7d 21 7d 28 7d 20 7d 36 7d 23 7d 26 7d   ~€!}!}(} }6}#}&}  
    20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 81 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20    } } } }&} } }   
    7d 20 83 7d 26 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 20 7d 33 cf   } ƒ}&} } } } }3Ï  
    7e 7e ff 7d 23 c0 21 7d 26 7d 21 7d 20 7d 24 f0   ~~ÿ}#À!}&}!} }$ð  
    e2 7e                                             â~                
[16/03/2020 18:33:11] - Close port COM6 

[16/03/2020 18:33:11] Read data (COM6)  
    0d 0a 4e 4f 20 43 41 52 52 49 45 52 0d 0a         ..NO CARRIER..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a combination of the way the TOBY-L200 maintains a persistent default EPS bearer, and an apparent policy of the cellular carrier account not to allow multiple IP addresses to be obtained by the same device on the network.

On bootup, the default EPS bearer setting causes an IP address to be obtained automatically, preventing the subsequent attempt to acquire a second IP address from being allowed during the PPP negotiation.

When the PPP negotiation previously worked, no default EPS bearer was configured, and I was unaware that the default EPS bearer was later set inadvertently.